# An extension of algebraic torus

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, lie-groups, algebraic-groups

Let $T_1$ and $T_2$ be algebraic tori over a field of characteristic 0. Let $T$ be an extension of $T_1$ by $T_2$, namely
$$
1\longrightarrow T_1\longrightarrow T\longrightarrow T_2\longrightarrow 1.
$$ Is $T$ necessarily an algebraic torus? If so, is there any simple proof?

Comment: This doesn't completely solve your problem since it assumes an algebraically closed field, but [this](https://blog.jpolak.org/?p=1125) might be of interest.

Comment: @MartinSkilleter, [that](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/413179/an-extension-of-algebraic-torus#comment1059067_413179) *does* solve the problem, because @‍Windi's condition is preserved under base change to $\overline k$, and because $T_{\overline k}$ a torus implies $T$ a torus.

Comment: Or just more simply, being a torus is an absolute notion, independently of fields of definition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@MartinSkilleter has posted an [answer](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/413179/an-extension-of-algebraic-torus#comment1059067_413179) in the comments.  I'll summarise here an elementary proof; it is almost the same as in @MartinSkilleter's link [Extensions of tori by tori are tori](https://blog.jpolak.org/?p=1125), just written slightly differently.

Let $k$ be the field of definition.  Since $k$ has characteristic $0$, the group scheme $T$ is smooth.  (In general, we could observe that $0 \to \operatorname{Lie}(T_1) \to \operatorname{Lie}(T) \to \operatorname{Lie}(T_2)$ is exact, so that $\dim \operatorname{Lie}(T)$ is at most $\dim \operatorname{Lie}(T_1) + \dim \operatorname{Lie}(T_2) = \dim T$, whence $\dim \operatorname{Lie}(T)$ equals $\dim T$ and so we have equality.)  Since $T$ is connected, it suffices to show that all points of $T(\overline k)$ are semisimple.  Consider $g \in T(\overline k)$.  Then the unipotent part $g_u$ of $g$ maps to the unipotent part of the image of $g$ in $T_2(\overline k)$, hence is trivial because $T_2$ is a torus; so $g_u$ belongs to $T_1(\overline k)$, hence is trivial because $T_1$ is a torus.